# Filter strings in Array based on content (filter search value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am running into an issue, I have a similar array of Strings in JS:

```
var myArray = ["bedroomone", "bedroomonetwo", "bathroom"];
```

And I would like to retrieve all the elements in the array that contains the keyword 'bedroom'. How can I achieve such result ?

I tried in different ways without getting the desired result. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: var resultsfilter = myArray.filter(function (element) { return element !== "bedroom"});
console.log(resultsfilter);

Comment: `!==` does an exact comparison. You need something like `/bedroom/.test(element)`

Comment: String.indexOf is good enough. You don't need a regex for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: var resultsfilter = myArray.filter(function (element) { return /bedroom/.test(element)});  ????

Comment: Right, or `.indexOf()` - the performance differences are uninteresting in general so use whichever you think is prettier.

Comment: I used this:  `var resultsfilter = myArray.filter(function (element) { return element.indexOf("bedroom") > -1});`  but it shows only these items: `"bedroomone", "bedroomonetwo"`, I mean what I dont need.

Comment: Then `return !/bedroom/.test(element)`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var PATTERN = 'bedroom',
    filtered = myArray.filter(function (str) { return str.indexOf(PATTERN) === -1; });
```

[Regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var PATTERN = /bedroom/,
    filtered = myArray.filter(function (str) { return PATTERN.test(str); });
```

[String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (only in moderm browsers):

```
var PATTERN = 'bedroom',
    filtered = myArray.filter(function (str) { return str.includes(PATTERN); });
```

Comment: I think that the condition in the indexOf function should be str.indexOf(PATTERN) > -1

Answer (score 56):

```
var bedrooms = myArray.filter(name => name.includes('bedroom'))
```

Comment: Please include some information about why this works!

Comment: I know this is old, but answers on SO are supposed to give some form of explanation rather than just code.

Answer (score 7):

Using JavaScript arrow function is much simpler

```js
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]

// search using keyword from array

var keywordToSearch = 'Arslan'; // word to search
var keyword =   keywordToSearch.toLowerCase();
var names = [{id: 1, name: 'Aqib'}, {id: 2, name: 'Arslan'}];

//search keyword from names array by name
var searchResult = names.filter(word => word.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1);
console.log(searchResult);
// expected output: > Array [Object { id: 2, name: "Arslan" }]
```

```html
Using javascript arrow function
```

Comment: If I have array for search: keywordToSearch =['test','something']. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Improved Microfed's answer to this

```
var textToSearch = 'bedroom';
var filteredArray = myArray.filter((str)=>{
  return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(textToSearch.toLowerCase()) >= 0; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the search() method

> Finds the first substring match in a regular expression search.
>
> (method) String.search(regexp: string | RegExp): number (+1 overload)

```
const filterList = (data, query) => {
        return data.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const House = ["bedroomone", "bedroomtwo", "bathroom"]
const filterItems = (arr, query) => {
    return arr.filter(element => 
    element.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
}
console.log(filterItems(House, "bedroom"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).