# Array.prototype.includes() with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235794/filter-strings-in-array-based-on-content) answer here was about how to filter an array using Array.prototype.includes(). Is there a way to
filter an object like this:

```
var myArray = [
{
  title: 'bedroomoneone',
},
{
  title: 'bedroomonetwo',
},
{
  title: 'bathroom',
},];
```

with the same behavior as Array.prototype.includes() or something similar? The solution to the link I provided above basically filters an array of strings and finds an item that has a specified keyword in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const myArray = [ { title: 'bedroomoneone' }, { title: 'bedroomonetwo' }, { title: 'bathroom' } ];

const res = myArray.filter(({title}) => title.includes('bedroom'));

console.log(res);
```